# How to find the nearest prime for a given number using for loop in C?

Tags: c, primes

I really tried but still don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int minus, i, judge;
  for (minus = 0, judge = 1; judge == 1; minus++, n -= minus) {
    for (i = 2; i * i < n; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0)
        judge = 1;
      else judge = 0;
    }
    if (judge == 1)
      continue;
    else break;
  }
  printf("%d\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

When I input 143, the output is 143 not 139.
However, when I input 11, the output is the correct answer 11.

Comment: Cheer, with `n==6`, do you care if the nearest prime is 5 or 7?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: If there are two primes with the same distance, print the larger one. But since I fail in the minus part, I haven't started the add part yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop test is incorrect: `for (i = 2; i * i < n; i++)`

If `n` is the square of a prime number, the loop will stop just before finding the factor.

You should either use `i * i <= n` or `i <= n / i`.

Furthermore, you do not enumerate all numbers as you decrement `n` by an increasing value at each iteration.

Note also that the loop would not find the closest prime to `n`, but the greatest prime smaller than `n`, which is not exactly the same thing.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(int n) {
    if (n <= 2 || n % 2 == 0)
        return n == 2;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n / i; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int n;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;

    if (n <= 2) {
        printf("2\n");
    } else {
        for (i = 0;; i++) {
            if (isPrime(n - i))
                printf("%d\n", n - i);
                break;
            }
            if (n <= INT_MAX - i && isPrime(n + i))
                printf("%d\n", n + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your current version of `isPrime` will consider 4,6,8,10,14... primes.

Comment: @wimh: sharp eyes! answer amended. Thank you

Comment: Works well as long as `n-i`, `n+i` does not overflow.  Likely meets OP's needs

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Good point, I added the appropriate tests. Should work for all `int` values.

Comment: `if (n <= 2) { printf("2\n");` --> Nice way to handle a lot of troublesome `n`.   See also [2147483647](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10059/what-is-the-largest-prime-less-than-231)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: it is actually debatable whether `-3` should produce `-3` or `2`... But mathematicians seem to agree that *prime numbers* should be positive. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002459/do-we-have-negative-prime-numbers